# why spin_lock should disable preempt? if not disable preempt what will happend?

Tags: kernel, spinlock, preemption

For this situation:  Process B will wait Process A release spin,so preemt OK ???
   
      `Process A:
       -->spin lock --> do strict call --> before unlock time int`
   
   `Time int ISR:
       --> Process A time slice finished --> need schedule
       -->ISR ret --> schedule to Process B`
   
   `Process B:
       -->spin lock for same resource --> failed --> spin wait`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the situation you provided *Process B* will **busy wait** until its slice ends and rescheduling to *Process A* occures. So, whole **time slice** would be **a wasting of the time**.

Things may be worse if switching from *Process B* to *Process A* is never occures. E.g., if priority of the *Process B* is more than one of the *Process A*. In that case it is **deadlock**.

Disabling preemption in `spin_lock` protects from both wasting of time and deadlock described above.